# I want to alternate in between players for a tic-tac-toe game. Why won't this code work?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

Why won't this code work?  If this isn't the best solution, please explain why this isn't working and what the best solution is.  This is my first game.

```
def players():
    marks = 'o', 'x'
    player1 = None
    player2 = None
    mark = input("Who are you? ").lower()
    if mark == 'o':
        player1 = 'o'
        player2 = 'x'
    else:
        player1 = 'x'
        player2 = 'o'
    for i in range(21):
        if player1 == True:
            print(player1)
            player1 = False
        else:
            print(player2)
            player1 = True
```

The range(21) line of code was just to test and see if it worked or not.  It did not.  When I type 'x', it just returns 'o' and then True over and over again.  I want it to say 'x' and 'o' over and over again.

Comment: You're overwriting `player1` (which stores the letter "x") with `True` in your loop. You need to use a different variable for that.

Comment: what do you want the for-loop to eventually do? If you need to check whose turn it is, I'd use a different field for this. For example you could init with `playerOnesTurn = player1=='o'`, and then have an if-loop. `if playerOnesTurn: # do something`; at each step, set `playerOnesTurn = not playerOnesTurn` so that the players switch turns. I would also suggest using an array of length 9 to store the state of the tic-tac-toe board. (0-2 is top row, 3-5 is 2nd row, 6-8 is last row), as you'll eventually need some container for that information

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `player1` to be `True` or `False`, that is why you do not see `'x'` being printed.

What you should do is add a third variable that stores whose turn it is to play. Having a simple boolean variable as you are attempting is fine, but let me show you a way that easily extends to games with more than one player by cycling over a list of players.

Also note that the first three lines of your functions are unused and you can thus remove them.

```
def players():
    mark = input("Who are you? ").lower()

    if mark == 'o':
        player1 = 'o'
        player2 = 'x'
    else:
        player1 = 'x'
        player2 = 'o'

    # We keep both a list of players and the index of the next to play
    players = [player1, player2]
    turn = 0

    for i in range(21):
        print(players[turn])

        # The modulo operator allows us to cycle over our list
        turn = (turn + 1) % len(players)

players()
```

Here is the output which I truncated since we get the idea after a few lines.

```
Who are you? x
x
o
x
o
...
```